# code coverage not covering if conditions

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to get coverage for my apex code but apparently it is not covering a simple if condition. Any idea why?

```
Picklist_Class.getPickListValue('Case','Type');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is apparently throwing an exception, as that's the only way this sort of situation can occur. Notice also that your return statement never executes. If your test is passing, I presume that you used a try-catch block in your unit test method, which is why it still succeeds. Never use try-catch in a unit test unless you're specifically testing for a thrown exception.

Comment: try catch seems to be the issue. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: @Akash You're welcome!